# Allow domain access only from mobile app and block website

Tags: .htaccess, rest, redirect

I have my api on the same domain as my website (ex: www.xyz.com), I want to make this domain only accessible from mobile application (API calls), while at the same time, any user who would try to access the website on the same domain should be redirected to maintenance page. I've already searched google for this and I cannot find anything.

P.S: calls/requests from mobile goes first to a file called "delegator.php" on my domain (www.xyz.com), then the delegator redirects to corresponding controllers,

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution for this?  I too am looking to do the same thing.  My API is already bound to https with proper certs but I want to lock it down even further.  I am trying to think of ways to add deny/allow statements to .htaccess but at the moment I can't find anything concrete on how to do this.

Comment: The only solution I found is to apply some authentication in your API to validate the client (may be you can use Oauth) so that you only register your mobile App to be allowed to use your API